# Finding elements in a 3x3 array

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to programming, and I have created a tic-tac-toe game. The game completely works, but I would like to add some "intelligence" to the computer.

The traditional 3 by 3 tic tac toe board (looks like "#") is being represented by an array, where all the elements(all the values) are initially set to zero. When a player chooses his/her position, the value changes to 1. For example, if a player put a X in the top right hand corner, array[0][2] becomes 1. If a player puts a X in the bottom left hand corner, array[2][0] becomes 1.

I'm trying to create two methods, one which returns the row (denoted by r())and another that returns the column(denoted by c()) of the coordinate of where the player would have to place the final X such that they win (). Basically I'm trying to make methods that return the location of where the player would need to place the final X to win, so the computer can block it.

I've tried searching the array using loops looking for a sum of 2, but I'm completely lost. Any help is appreciated. Also any advice for offense "intelligence" would be helpful.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TicTacToe {

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static int[][] grid;
    private static final int XPOS = 1;
    private static final int OPOS = -1;
    private static final int EMPTY = 0;


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//game


        do {
            initBoard();

            do {
                moveX();

                if (isTicTacToe()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X wins");
                } else if (isCatsGame()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cats Game");
                } else {
                    moveO();
                    if (isTicTacToe()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O wins");
                    }
                }

            } while (!isCatsGame() && !isTicTacToe());
        } while (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Playagain?") == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    }

 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Methods

    public static void moveX() {
        // PRECONDITION: The grid is initialized and not full
        // POSTCONDITION: XPOS is assigned to the location in grid chosen by the user

        // Algorithm: Ask the user for a location from 1-9, convert it to (r,c), 
        // make sure it is valid and empty, assign XPOS to that locaion

        int move;
        do {
            move = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(displayBoard()
                    + "\n\n Enter your move for X"));
        } while ((move < 1) || (move > 9)
                || grid[getRow(move)][getCol(move)] != EMPTY);
        grid[getRow(move)][getCol(move)] = XPOS;

    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void moveO() {
        // PRECONDITION: The grid is initialized and not full
        // POSTCONDITION: a random available location has been assigned OPOS

        int move = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);

        if (check(move, move) == true)  {
            grid[getRow(move)][getCol(move)] = OPOS;
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static boolean isTicTacToe() {
        // PRECONDITION:  grid is initialized
        // POSTCONDITION: Returns TRUE if there is a winner, FALSE otherwise

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(grid[i][0] + grid[i][1] + grid[i][2]) == 3) {
                return true;
            } else if (Math.abs(grid[0][i] + grid[1][i] + grid[2][i]) == 3) {
                return true;
            } else if (Math.abs(grid[0][0] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][2]) == 3) {
                return true;
            } else if (Math.abs(grid[0][2] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][0]) == 3) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void initBoard() {
        // PRECONDITION: 
        // POSTCONDITION: The grid has been initialize and all values set to EMPTY//initilize the board by creating a 3 by 3 array of integers

        grid = new int[3][3];
        // Make all the vakues empty
        for (int i = 0; i > grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j > grid.length; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static boolean isCatsGame() {
        // PRECONDITION: The grid is initialized
        // POSTCONDITION: returns TRUE if there are no EMPTY spots, FALSE otherwise

        for (int r = 0; r >= 2; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c >= 2; c++) {
                if (grid[r][c] == EMPTY) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static int getRow(int n) {
        // PRECONDITION: 1 <= n <= 9
        // POSTCONDITION: returns the correct row - 0, 1, or 2
        return ((n - 1) / 3);
    }

    private static int getCol(int n) {
        // PRECONDITION: 1 <= n <= 9
        // POSTCONDITION: returns the correct col - 0, 1, or 2
        return ((n - 1) % 3);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static String displayBoard() {
        // PRECONDITION: The grid is initialized
        // POSTCONDITION: returns a string representatin of the grid to be used
        //                in a JOPTIONPANE (\n's but no \t's).
        //                XPOS is replaced with X, OPOS with O, 
        //                EMPTY with the correct number 1 - 9

        String s = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            int r = getRow(i);
            int c = getCol(i);
            if (grid[r][c] == EMPTY) {
                s += " " + i;
            } else if (grid[r][c] == XPOS) {
                s += " X";
            } else {
                s += " O";
            }
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                s += "\n";
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static boolean check(int x, int y) {
        //PRECONDITION: CHECKS IF A COORDINATE ON THE TABLE IS OCCUPIED
        //POSTCONDITION: RETURNS TRUE IF ITS NOT BEING USED
        if (grid[getRow(x)][getCol(y)] != EMPTY) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //need a method to see if there is two in a row, and one to find where the 
    // winning x,y coordinate is 
    private static boolean matchPoint() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(grid[i][0] + grid[i][1] + grid[i][2]) == 2) {
                return true;
            } else if (Math.abs(grid[0][i] + grid[1][i] + grid[2][i]) == 2) {
                return true;
            } else if (Math.abs(grid[0][0] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][2]) == 2) {
                return true;
            } else if (Math.abs(grid[0][2] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][0]) == 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static int r() {

    }

    private static int c() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more complex game with perfect information and alternating moves, there exists plentyful game theory. Games like Chess, Go, TicTacToe, Mills and Tak all underly the same basic rule set. However TicTacToe is simplified, because the options are so limited, that you can basically 'work around' the complex solving way, and could implement a direct way, by making very direct placement decisions.

Usually such games are solved creating a ply-tree. This is a search tree, where all the possible placements are run through. However (most of) these games are not solvable this way, because the trees are too lagre (they grow exponentially with every ply you try to look ahead). But for TicTacToe, which is so small and simple, you actually can solve the tree, without running out of time or memory.

When searching in a tree like this, you usually don't separate the functions to x and y, but handle both together (for example with a `Point` or `Coordinate` class). Use a recursive algorithm to grind through all options and then place your piece according to the best option available to your AIs player.

(That said, I personally would recommend you to diverge from the iterative way you code and go a bit more into Object-Oriented programming. That way the code becomes more readable and you can isolate problems better)

Hint:
Since the board is square, and the pieces are 'flat', you can simplify the tree by 'merging' board positions. For example, the following two scenarios are (effectively)  the same:

```
X|  |
------
 |O |
------
 |  |
```

and

```
 |  |X
------
 |O | 
------
 |  |
```

So when you 'search' for the right move, you can tread them as the same, as long as you can later still figure out which way you turned and/or flipped the board, to figure out the right placement.
But even without this simplificytion you should be able to solve the tree fairly easiely.

When you are done implementing TicTacToe, take a look at the board game 'Tak'.
Multiple open source AIs have been written, and the game is more fun than TicTacToe in the long run ;)
https://www.playtak.com/ (Find the rules under 'Help'. There are multiple interesting links there).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same logic as in your `isTicTacToe()` method, and look up the possible position in your `grid` table and return it, or `null` if no such position could be found. For example:

```
import java.awt.Point;
// ...
Point getPointToWin() {
    // look for wc (win condition) and return it if found, otherwise null
    for(int r=0; r<grid.length; r++) {
        for(int c=0; c<grid[0].length; c++) {
            // skip if not X
            if(grid[r][c]!=XPOS)
                continue;
            // lookup wc in top row
            if(r==0)
                if(c==0) {
                    if(grid[r][c+1]==XPOS)
                        return new Point(r,c+2)
                    if(grid[r+1][c+1]==XPOS)
                        return new Point(r+2,c+2)
                    if(grid[r+1][c]==XPOS)
                        return new Point(r+2,c)
                }
                elseif(c==1) {
                    // ... top row, center column
                }
                elseif(c==2) {
                    // ... top row, right column
                }
            elseif(r==1) {
                // ... center row, left/center/right column
            }
            elseif(r==2) {
                // ... bottom row, left/center/right column
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To make it as short as possible, i only wrote the wc lookup logic if an X was found in right row, top column. You would then have to write the logic for the remaining 8 possible positions of an X.